# resource.getrusage always yields the same results

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I am trying to come up with my own memory measurement decorator. For my purposes, libs like memory profiler do not suit.
Inspired by [this article](https://medium.com/survata-engineering-blog/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program-49f027e3d1ba), I have drafted the following code.

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import resource
from time import sleep

def test():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 7)
    time.sleep(3)


class MemoryMonitor:

    def __init__(self):
        self.keep_measuring = True

    def measure_usage(self):
        max_usage = 0
        while self.keep_measuring:

            max_usage = max(
                max_usage,
                resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
            )
            sleep(0.1)
        return max_usage


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func = test
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        monitor = MemoryMonitor()
        mem_thread = executor.submit(monitor.measure_usage)
        try:
            fn_thread = executor.submit(func)
            result = fn_thread.result()
        finally:
            monitor.keep_measuring = False
            max_usage = mem_thread.result()
        print("Peak memory usage for {}: {}".format(func.__name__, max_usage))
```

The strange thing for me is that for some reason, it always yields the same max usage result, no matter if I put `a = [1] * (10 ** 7)` or `a = [1] * (10 ** 6)`, or `a = [1] * (10 ** 5)`. Is there somethiing I am missing ?

Comment: have you ever worked this out?